# How can I mock NSLocale.preferredLanguages in Swift to test requests?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, mocking, tdd

I am testing the requests my app creates, specifically "Accept-Language" and its value "en-US;q=1.0" through request?.allHTTPHeaderFields?["Accept-Language"]

I don't have problems with that in ObjC, I use OCMock to mock NSLocale preferredLanguages (because that changes depending on the iOS or MAC computer you use).

Now I am using Swift and I know that Swift is a read-only language (cannot change in real time).

So, how can I achieve this?

Clearly, I cannot create my own NSLocale mock and inject it into NSURLRequest, because that is a private class.
Maybe using swizzling (no idea), or perhaps a trick using extensions, no idea.

Do you have any idea or advice? Thanks a lot.

EDIT:
As NSLocale is an NSObject, perhaps I can use a similar approach to this one:
https://github.com/kylef/Mockingjay/blob/master/Mockingjay/NSURLSessionConfiguration.swift

Comment: *"Swift is a read-only language"* – What do you mean?

Comment: That means that reflection is very limited. The opposite of objc
https://realm.io/news/tryswift-veronica-ray-real-world-mocking-swift/

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to stub preferredLanguages under Swift using swizzle, writing this inside the test.

```
// stub preferredLanguages before all the tests start
override class func setUp() {
    WAClientTests.exchangePreferredLanguagesImplementation()
}

// stop stubbing preferredLanguages after passing all tests
override class func tearDown() {
    WAClientTests.exchangePreferredLanguagesImplementation()
}

static func stubPreferredLanguages() -> [String] {
    return ["en-US"]
}

class func exchangePreferredLanguagesImplementation() {
    let originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(NSLocale.classForCoder(), #selector(NSLocale.preferredLanguages))
    let swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(WAClientTests.classForCoder(), #selector(WAClientTests.stubPreferredLanguages))
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod)
}
```

Comment: Super helpful, didn't know Swift could swizzle methods like that. Thanks!

Comment: @robmathers It is not because Swift, it's because NSLocale is a subclass of NSObject. At that is not always the case.

Comment: Why is the call needed on both setup and tear down?

Answer (score 0):

A slightly updated version of [Ricardo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38951886/3165453) for Swift 5.8

```
extension NSLocale {
    static var localeIds: [String] = []
    
    @objc static func mockPreferredLanguages() -> [String] {
        return localeIds
    }
    
    static func mock(preferredLanguages localeIds: [String], closure: () -> Void) {
        Self.localeIds = localeIds
        exchangePreferredLanguagesImplementation() // replace original with stubbed
        closure()
        exchangePreferredLanguagesImplementation() // replace stubbed with original
    }
    
    private static func exchangePreferredLanguagesImplementation() {
        let originalMethod = class_getClassMethod(NSLocale.classForCoder(), #selector(getter: NSLocale.preferredLanguages))
        let swizzledMethod = class_getClassMethod(NSLocale.classForCoder(), #selector(NSLocale.mockPreferredLanguages))
        method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod!, swizzledMethod!)
    }
}
```

Use like this:

```
func test_myLocaleSensitiveTest_() {
    NSLocale.mock(preferredLanguages: ["en_US"]) {
        // Put your tests here
        sut.doAction()
        XCTAssertEqual(..)
        XCTAssertEqual(..)
    }
}
```